# Group content side by side possibly spanning more than a single page

Tags: floats, page-breaking, minipage

I have data consisting of groups of key-value pairs and associated images. I'd like the key-value pairs to show in a table to the right of the images. Like this:

[image: LaTeX screenshot]

The above screenshot is produced by the following code:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
  \vspace{0pt}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.55\textwidth}
  \vspace{0pt}
  \begin{tabular}{ >{\bfseries \raggedleft}p{0.4\textwidth}<{:}  p{.6\textwidth}  }
    Key & Value \\
    Another key & 56.1481049 \\
    Ipsum bla & Lorem tutasee \\
    Kvalatit & Tip top \\
    Fordus tius & Lorem ipsum bla supresium vitales ektum eksaput doktinus mit dei fyrte granikus.\\
    Estimat is & 1337 \\
    Lokale & Viktualierum \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
```

The code works as I want and several groups of tables and images can be placed after each other.

However unfortunately it seems that a minipage is restricted to a single page. Thus, if the images or the table takes more space than a single page, they will simply overflow the page and continue on into non-existence.

Is there any way that I can achieve what I want in a way so that if possible the tables aren't broken across several pages but in the cases where the minipages simply can't fit in a page they behave decently?

[image: Figure of the desired result]

The above is a rough illustration of what I'd like to end op with. That is: the tabels/images only breaks on pages when they have to, otherwise they act like normal LaTeX floats.

Comment: neither the minipage nor the nested tabular (if you removed the minipage) will break over a page, It looks like you want a list for the text (which will break over a page) then put the images in the margin using \marginpar or similar (with a wide left margin)

Comment: But i _only_ want the things to break over a page when the content is longer than a page and absolutely has to.

Comment: so you can set the inter-line penalties within the list to be very high.

Comment: Could maybe create and answer with an example? I've no experience with penalties and I'm not sure how you'll get the same look for the key-value pairs with a list?

Comment: I would have thought about `\marginnote{}` the illustrations at places where you want them. As far as I remember, you might want then to have a smaller textwidth but more margin... That's my current idea.

Comment: So I'll have one `\marginnote{}` per table with the images? Will that make things break correctly? I'm thinking for instance if the combined height of the images is larger than the table wouldn't the next table be placed directly below the previous table and not below where the last picture ended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take advantage of the new scrlayer packages in the new KOMA-script version (3.12). The column in the margin will continue, if necessary, on the next page. To me, this seems something rather new. However, you'd need longtable and I did not really test that. Just as an example I add some code, but you'll have to play with the width and the margins...

```
\documentclass[pagesize]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn, scrlayer-scrpage, graphicx, calc, longtable}


 \DeclareNewNoteColumn[font=\sffamily\footnotesize, width=3cm, 
 position=\oddsidemargin+1in+\textwidth-3cm+\marginparsep]{randnot}




\begin{document}
\begin{addmargin}[0cm]{3cm}
  \makenote[randnot]{%
    \protect\begin{longtable}{p{1.5cm}p{2cm} }
      Key & Value \\
      Another key & 56.1481049 \\
      Ipsum bla & Lorem tutasee \\
      Kvalatit & Tip top \\
      Fordus tius & Lorem ipsum bla supresium vitales ektum eksaput doktinus mit dei fyrte granikus.\\
      Estimat is & 1337 \\
      Lokale & Viktualierum \\
      \protect\end{longtable} }
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image}%
\end{addmargin}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure that the version of KOMA-script you mention is available to me (I'm using texlive from the Ubuntu repos).

Comment: @paldepind This should be interesting for you: [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092)

Comment: Alex, better use an image from package mwe, and perhaps add package `showframe`, so one can see better the overlapping of margin.

Comment: Sorry. I've played around with your code, and I can not get it to display properly.

Comment: @paldepind No need to be sorry, but this code runs on my machine so probably your installations includes older versions of KOMA-script files. `\listfiles` at the beginning of the code will print all files into the log and you can look out for the culprit.

Comment: Sure, it runs for me as well. This is on a fresh net install of TeXLive so it shouldn't be outdated. It's the output that's not really what I'm after. It appears as if the image aligns to the left and the table to the right. Also when several image and table groups appear after each other they don't start at the same position at the page.

Comment: @paldepind Please, provide an example. I'm quite sure with scrlayer we can meet your demands, but I need something to work with.

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed your comment. This is the LaTeX I tested based on your suggestion: http://pastebin.com/1i8LWpZ9
It doesn't look very much like what I'd like to end up with.

Comment: @KeksDose, have you looked at my code dump? I'm still looking for a proper solution to this problem :)

Comment: @paldepind »It doesn't look very much like what I'd like to end up with« OK, and why? And please leave an image file as an example at pastebin, if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fairly simplistic solution using [`longtable`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/longtable), together with [`adjustbox`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/adjustbox) to help with vertical alignment of the figures.

[image: screenshot]

I have used a simple `itemize` list for your 'key-value' list, and used the [`enumitem`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) to help with the formatting of it.

Note that the [`longtable`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/longtable) environment will never break *cells* across pages, but will happily put page breaks between rows, which sounded like it was your main goal- the output should be almost exactly as it is in your mock-up, although you may get some bad pagination depending on the dimensions of your images.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes, trace: yes, localSettings: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{.4\textwidth}p{.6\textwidth}}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-a}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-b}
    &
    \begin{itemize}[font=\bfseries,leftmargin=2.5cm]
        \item[Key] Value
        \item[Another key] 56.1481049
        \item[Ipsum bla] Lorem tutasee
        \item[Kvalatit] Tip top
        \item[Fordus tius] Lorem ipsum bla supresium vitales
              ektum eksaput doktinus mit dei fyrte granikus.
        \item[Estimat is] 1337
        \item[Lokale] Viktualierum
    \end{itemize}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `longtable` you're using here has only a single row per data/image set. Doesn't this mean that this solution has the exactly same problem as my original one if one set of data or images takes up more space than a page?

Comment: @paldepind you're correct, it does have that limitation. The mark up is slightly more robust in my solution because we don't have to specify a `minipage` every time, and we only have to specify the column widths once. If you have a set of data that takes up more than a page, you're going to have to tweak it manually; perhaps you might be interested in [grid typesetting](https://www.google.com/search?q=grid+typesetting&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a). Thanks for the bounty, I appreciate it :)

Comment: Unfortunately manual tweaking is not an option for me since the LaTeX file is automatically generated based on data from a database.